# Compiling: conflicting types for 'sigset_t'

Tags: unix, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to compile the wazuh manager. I've done the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc make git libc6-dev
$ mkdir ossec_tmp && cd ossec_tmp
$ git clone -b stable https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh.git ossec-wazuh
$ cd ossec-wazuh
$ sudo ./install.sh
```

This gives me an error as such:

```
In file included from /usr/include/asm/signal.h:26:0,
                 from /usr/include/linux/signal.h:5,
                 from /usr/include/linux/aio_abi.h:32,
                 from engines/afalg/e_afalg.c:43:
/usr/include/asm-generic/signal.h:92:3: error: conflicting types for 'sigset_t'
 } sigset_t;
```

I then went and tried compiling without shared library only the agent by running:

```
sudo make -C src DISABLE_SHARED=1 TARGET=agent
```

This seem to give the exact same error. Anyone able to assist me here to debug?

Comment: `sudo ./install.sh` is a little too brave for my taste...

Comment: `sudo make`?! Why would you do that?

Comment: Is that the whole error message?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to follow the manager installation guide of our documentation.

As I can see you want to install the server in a folder called 'ossec_tmp', I recommend you to create the folder and after that following the guide, when you launch

```
./install
```

It will ask you for the path where you want to install the service.
Here is a link to the documentation:

https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/installing-wazuh-server/sources_installation.html

Hope it helps.